# What is the correct way to add a NPM package to a Laravel 9 project with Laravel Mix?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, editor.md

[Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com) introduces itself as

> An elegant wrapper around Webpack for the 80% use case.

I believe I have a widespread use case, and I want to know if the 80% covers this and how to do it right. It could be any other package, but I have [editor.md](https://github.com/pandao/editor.md) as an example. They want you to install it with `npm i editor.md` and use it like the following.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="editor.md/css/editormd.min.css" />
<div id="editor">
    <!-- Tips: Editor.md can auto append a `<textarea>` tag -->
    <textarea style="display:none;">### Hello Editor.md !</textarea>
</div>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="editor.md/editormd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var editor = editormd("editor", {
            // width: "100%",
            // height: "100%",
            // markdown: "xxxx",     // dynamic set Markdown text
            path : "editor.md/lib/"  // Autoload modules mode, codemirror, marked... dependents libs path
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I want to know how to get the following paths right.

1. editor.md/css/editormd.min.css
2. jquery.min.js (not a dependency)
3. editor.md/editormd.min.js
4. editor.md/lib/

My ideas/questions:

I could copy the CSS and JS files with Mix.

```
mix.copy("node_modules/editor.md/css/editormd.min.css", "public/css/editormd.min.css");
mix.copy("node_modules/editor.md/editormd.min.js", "public/js/editormd.min.js");
```

But then I miss all the files from the lib folder (*4th path*). I could copy this folder as well. I could copy the entire `node_modules/editor.md` folder to my assets folder, but this feels too much. And finally, where is jQuery coming from? Do I add it from a CDN? Do I install the npm package? Again, I saw solutions requiring everything in the `app.js` file.

How to do it the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Laravel Mix, the correct way to implement this is to run the following.

```
npm i editor.md jquery
```

Then add your `require()` methods in the bootstrap.js file.

**resources/js/bootstrap.js**

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.editormd = require('editor.md');
} catch (exception) {
    console.error(exception);
}
```

In your template, likely located at **/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php**, you will need to add the following at the bottom of the file before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: First, thank you for updating my question to show me how to ask more clearly. Unfortunately this isn't working because of an issue with the package itself: `The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.`. As this is too complex to resolve for me, unfortunately I think I need to copy the entire folder.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to do it, but you could copy the entire directory with `mix.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir)` as seen [here](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/copying-files)

Comment: The feels like not to be the bet way for me as well. If I do that, you couldn't I just use the direct path to node_modules? It would reduce the size of my repo.

Comment: When you push to server, node_modules don't go with you, and they stay up to date. In terms of direct path, you shouldn't be able to access node_modules from the frontend, only assets in the `public/` directory